# Find first character in JTextArea after whitespaces

Tags: java, jtextarea

I'm trying to figure out how to write a code for program that detects where is the beginning of text in JTextArea if user inputs whitespaces before any text. Depending of first symbol of text after all whitespaces program does one of 2 methods. Ml if first character is "." or "-", otherwise lm. Here is what I got:

```
    output.setText("");
    int i = 0;
    char array[] = (input.getText()).toCharArray();
    while(Character.toString(array[i]).equals("")){
        i++;
    }
        if (array.length < i || !Character.toString(array[i]).equals(".") && !Character.toString(array[i]).equals("-")){
            lm();   
        } else {
            ml();
        } return output.getText();
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Do you just want to find the first character in the input that is not a blank ("") or a whitespace character (" ") ? And, do you care where that location is within the text, or are you just trying to clean the input up before using it?

Comment: The program checks only the first character. If it's whitespace, it has no sense. So I want it to check the next character after whitespace. If it's whitespace again, next character and so on.

Comment: You didn't exactly answer my question. What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to find the valid text within the input excluding whitespace or are you trying to find the location of the first valid character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about trim the string, this should take out white spaces from start and end of the string

```
  input.getText().trim()
```

Comment: I agree trim is helpful - If the OP is just trying to clean the string. But his question is stated in such a way that he makes it seem like he is trying to figure out where the first valid char is. So, this is not really addressing the question as a valid answer based on the question as is.

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I just thought I should find the index of first character if there were whitespaces before it to compare it with "." or "-".

Answer (score 0):

> trim public String trim()
>
> Returns a string whose value is this string, with any leading and
>   trailing whitespace removed.  If this String object represents an
>   empty character sequence, or the first and last characters of
>   character sequence represented by this String object both have codes
>   greater than '\u0020' (the space character), then a reference to this
>   String object is returned.

```
String msg = "      this is a invaid spaced message     ";
        msg = msg.trim();
        System.out.println(msg);
```

and this prints:

> this is a invaid spaced message